# Asyncio.run gives RuntimeError loop is closed

Tags: python, python-asyncio, wsl-2, coap

When trying to create simple coap server with asyncronous function and asyncio.run it return Event loop is closed. Code below:

```
import aiocoap
import aiocoap.resource as resource


class CoAPServer(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    async def render_get(self, request):
        print("Received GET request ...")
        return aiocoap.Message(code=aiocoap.GET, payload="hello friend".encode('utf8'))

    async def render_post(self, request):
        print("Received POST request ...")
        return aiocoap.Message(code=aiocoap.CHANGED, payload="that's me".encode('utf8'))

async def main():
    root = resource.Site()
    root.add_resource(['demo'], CoAPServer)
    task = asyncio.create_task(aiocoap.Context.create_server_context(root, bind=('127.0.0.1', 5683)))
    await task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Gives this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function RecvmsgSelectorDatagramTransport.__del__ at 0x7f9a04c57310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiocoap/util/asyncio/recvmsg.py", line 95, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiocoap/util/asyncio/recvmsg.py", line 83, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._protocol.connection_lost, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Instead, if i use get_event_loop().run_forever() which is not recommended as per the docs

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio functions, such as asyncio.run(), and should rarely need to reference the loop object or call its methods. This section is intended mostly for authors of lower-level code, libraries, and frameworks, who need finer control over the event loop behavior.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

it works. Currently using python3.8.10 in wsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue resulting from aiocoap still using (and, in some places, using badly) idioms to support Python 3.7 or (in obsoleted parts) even previous versions.

I'm aware `asyncio.run()` is preferred, but until the next aiocoap release (in which I plan to update the examples too), the old idiom is what works best across the range of supported Python versions.

Comment: Sorry did not meant to be obnoxious with the best practices i cited, i was just trying to figure out if i was to blame, the docs or something else. Really appreciate your work!

Comment: Not obnoxious at all, it is a valid point, and the blame is with me still slopping on adopting modern asyncio.

Comment: The latest status (not released yet, but in the master branch) fixed the issue you're pointing out and a few others; please open a bug if you find anything that acts up when used with `asyncio.run()` now. (Or anything that acts up, really :-) )

Answer (score 0):

The code with `asyncio.run(main())` works fine on a Unix system. So, it's most likely an issue with how `aiocoap` deals with the event loop in a WSL environment. For now, you're better off using `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()` until the maintainers patches the library.

Comment: There is some weirdness in `asyncio.run()` even on Linux systems, eg. when interrupting programs with Ctrl-C. I think this stems from how I had tried to work around some of the problematic aspects of pre-`.run()` asyncio, eg. through manual handling of KeyboardInterrupt.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug of asyncio (on windows), see [GH-83413](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83413).

Fixed by [GH-92842](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92842) on May 2022, patched to 3.10.6+ and 3.11.0+.

For older version of python, using a workaround described in https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324 would be needed.